# Milk and Meat of Non-Kosher Animal Species

Tags: kashrut-kosher, animals, cooking-bishul, meat-and-milk

Is cooking milk with the meat of non-kosher animal species the same problem as cooking milk with the meat of kosher animal species?

In other words: can a Jew cook milk with a non-kosher animal species, such as a pig (and not eat it)? Can a Jew obtain benefit (הנאה) from such mixtures?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch, YD 87:3:

> אינו נוהג אלא בבשר בהמה טהורה בחלב בהמה טהורה אבל בשר טהורה בחלב טמאה או בשר טמאה בחלב טהורה מותרים בבישול ובהנאה
>
> "[The prohibition] is only relevant with regards to meat from a kosher animal in milk from a kosher animal, but with regards to meat from a kosher animal in milk from a non-kosher animal or meat from a non-kosher animal in milk from a kosher animal, they are permitted to cook and to derive benefit from."

Comment: Does a non-kosher animal in this context refers to an intrinsically non-kosher animal (בשר טמאה), or even to an intrinsically kosher animal that died or was improperly slaughtered?

Comment: @Menachem, the Hebrew text makes it clear that it's the _type_ of animal that matters.  Even if the specific animal being cooked is not Kosher because of how it was slaughtered, if it was a Kosher _type_ of _Behemah_ (eg., cow), then it may not be cooked with milk.  The translation could be clarified a bit.