# Is Pork, Camel, and the like Fleishig?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, non-kosher-species

If one somehow consumed meat of a non-kosher species such as camel or pork (e.g. life-threatening illness, or by accident), does s/he become Fleishig?

Why or why not?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8085/759

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22900/does-neveilah-tereifah-make-you-fleishig

Comment: and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52861/waiting-after-meat-and-milk

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/117109/170

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason one "becomes fleishig", i.e. cannot eat dairy after eating meat, is because of remaining meat in his [mouth or esophagus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10166) which he cannot have with milk. Now, the *Shach* and *Taz* (and *Baer Hetev* after them, all at [87:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&pgnum=387)) say there's no meat-and-milk prohibition on eating milk *with* pork (or other non-kosher animals), so I'd have to assume there's also no problem with eating it afterward. But, as always, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) with practical questions.

Answer (score 5):

The earliest source I know of is [Mishna Chullin 8:4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%97), which says one is allowed to cook (and derive benefit from) meat from a non-kosher animal in kosher-animal milk, or meat from a kosher animal in non-kosher-animal milk.

Meat from a kosher animal (say, cattle), even if the meat itself is not kosher (e.g. it was not slaughtered) may not be cooked with milk.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22900 (which you may wish to post an answer to, JXG).

Answer (score 4):

Concurring with msh210. The Biblical prohibition on meat-with-milk only applies to kosher species. Presumably Chazal didn't bother adding a rabbinic prohibition if someone chooses to cook their pork in milk.

So no, it wouldn't render the person "fleishig."

Comment: +1. Not just "Presumably": The _Shach_ and _Taz_ I link to in my answer say that that's precisely the reason that the prohibition doesn't apply.