# Can non-kosher meat be eaten with fish?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat, health-safety-shmira, fish

The prohibition of mixing meat with milk and of deriving benefit from their mixture concerns only kosher meat (Hullin 8:4 [113a]; Hilkhot Maakhalot Assurot 9:3; Yoreh De'ah 87:3; etc). As such, it may follow that one who needs to eat non-kosher meat for whatever reason is not obligated to subsequently abstain from dairy. In other words, non-kosher meat does not render one [*fleishig*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fleischig) insofar as this prohibition is concerned.

But what about the prohibition of consuming meat together with fish (Yoreh De'ah 116:2)? In the event that one is required to eat non-kosher meat, can they eat it with fish as well, or is that still considered "dangerous"?

[**This is not a belated Purim question!**]

Comment: What would necessitate eating treif meat?

Comment: From the gemara in pesachim 76b it would seem any meat with fish can cause tzaaras,and even chicken is assur

Comment: Can non Kosher fish be eaten with meat?

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by non-kosher or kosher meat. Neveilah, for instance, is non-kosher meat, but I don't think that's what you mean to include. (or is it?)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22900/759

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt  I can't think of a case when a doctor would tell you that you __must__ eat pork or shrimp.  This would have to be one of those starving in a desert or drafted in an army situations.

Comment: may nafka mina?

Comment: @Mike, that's what I thought, however, I was unsure due to phrasing.

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, the Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 116:2 forbids the consumption of meat and fish products together, out of concern that it is unhealthy. Since this is a health issue, it should apply to all types of meat and fish. I say this because, if it only applied to certain types of fish and meat, then the Shulchan Oruch would have specified the cases in which it applied and those in which it did not.

I found a full discussion of this subject in [Fish and Meat by Aryeh Leibowitz](http://www.bknw.org/uploads/5/9/9/5/5995719/eating_fish_and_meat.pdf)

> Regardless of the origin of the prohibition, gemara Chullin 9a states
>   explicitly that one must treat dangerous activities with greater
>   stringency than one would treat halachically prohibited activities

Thus even though (as quoted below) the prohibition may not apply in our day, or may only apply to the specific fish mentioned in the gemoro, we still should refrain from mixing any type of meat and fish.

> It should be noted that recent research has found that stearic acid
>   found in beef may actually lower LDL cholesterol (See American Journal
>   of Clinical Nutrition 1994;60 (Suppl) : 1044s). On the other hand fish
>   contains eicosapentaenoic acid which has been found (paradoxically) to
>   INCREASE lipid peroxidation (J invest dermatology 1994;103:151; Intl J
>   Vitamin Nutrition Res 1994;64: 144; Journal of Nutrition
>   1992;122:2190; Journal of Lipid Research 1991;32:79). In addition
>   there may be an interaction in the liver (P450) between stearic acid
>   and eicosapentaenoic acid. This being said, there is no evidence to
>   indicate that drinking some schnopps in between would in any way solve
>   this problem.
>
> The opinion of Magen Avraham. The Magen Avraham (Orach  Chaim 173)
>   writes that there are many natural phenomena  mentioned in the gemara
>   that simply no longer apply today. The  health concern of eating meat
>   and fish is simply another example  of something that used to be a
>   real concern, but is simply no  longer an issue. Perhaps this can be
>   supported by the fact that the  Rambam omits this concern from his
>   Mishnah Torah entirely.  The Chatam Sofer (Responsa 101) offers two
>   explanations for  the omission of the Rambam. First, he suggests, it
>   is possible that  the Rambam knew that the gemara was only concerned
>   with the  specific fish mentioned in Pesachim 76b, but all other fish
>   really  pose no danger when mixed with meat. Alternatively, Chatam 
>   Sofer suggests, the Rambam knew that nature has changed and  although
>   there one was a legitimate health threat posed by  mixing fish and
>   meat, no such threat exists today. (It is important  to note that
>   Chatam Sofer does not recommend that we rely on  the Rambam’s opinion
>   in this area.)