# Intentionally smelling the odor of food cooked by a Jew on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul, smell

Since it is forbidden to benefit from food cooked by a Jew on Shabbos, is the benefit only eating, or is it prohibited to intentionally smell the odor of the food being cooked as well?

Comment: The general halachic principle is that smell does not count as benefit, see discussion here. Feel free to smell away. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40343/am-i-allowed-to-enjoy-the-smell-emanating-from-a-non-kosher-place-that-cooks-usi?r=SearchResults

Comment: However, the answer given there says “The Kaf Hachayim on Yore Deah 108:70 and Darkei Teshuva 108:102 conclude that one may not smell those things that are Assur Behana'ah, but one may smell things that are only Assur Ba'achilah.”  Since food cooked on shabbos is assur b’hana’ah, shouldn’t it be forbidden to smell it according to these poskim?

Answer (score 1):

The Shach in Yore Dea 108,7 says:

> זה הכלל כל מידי דלא הוי להריח ריחא לאו מילתא היא אבל דבר שעומד להריח כגון ורד והדס אסור ליהנות מהריח עכ"ל ב"י וכ"כ התוס' פ"ק דעבודת כוכבים דף י"ב אלא בורד והדס בשם ר"ת ותירץ בזה הא דמותר להריח ביין
>    This is the general rule: **Anything that is *not* designated for smelling e.g food/drink which is meant to be eaten like *stam Yayin* (wine of a gentile which is forbidden to drink), smelling it is not a problem**, but something which *is* designated for smelling e.g flowers for idol worship, one *cannot* benefit through smelling.